# Amazon Lambdas HTML post form submit

Tags: html, forms, aws-lambda

I want to POST to the AWS API Gateway.  I want my URL query strings to passed to an Amazon Lambda.

In the API Gateway configuration, I have in the Method Request specified a parameter as a URL Query String Parameter, `q4_englishName_first_`.   In the Integration Request, I have specified a `Content-Type "application/json"` mapping.  It looks like this:

```
{
    "first" : "$input.params('q4_englishName_first_')"
}
```

My lambda has a request class with `"first"` as a String, getters and setters...

When I test from the API Gateway console, I can specify a value for `"q4_englishName_first_"` -- it has a text entry area for me to do this -- and I leave the request body box blank.   When I click Test in the API Gateway, the result is success.  In my case, I am sent an email with the value I typed into the query string entry area.

It has been maddening that I have not had success any other way.  I would like to use a standard HTML form submit to pass the value:

```
<form action="https://foo-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/beta" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="q4_englishName_first_"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

But when I click submit, I get this back:

```
{"message": "Unsupported Media Type"}
```

This makes me think that the API Gateway is not expecting a POST with Content-Type  `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.  I want to believe I'm right because when I wrote a Java program using Apache httpclient to do the POST, `Content-type "application/json"` goes through...

But I want to POST from a URL form, and I don't want to wait for forms to support JSON encoding.  Do I have to use javascript to translate the form params to JSON (how?) or is there some way to make the AWS API gateway accept my url encoded params?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to create an `ANY` method on a resource in API Gateway and set it to use the Lambda Proxy integration. Then everything in the request is passed to the Lambda function (including request parameters and body).